# AutoLisp DCL - Multi-line Text with Button

Tags: lisp, cad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I'm trying to reduce the width of a button by making the text inside the button two lines instead of one. I thought using `"\n"` would produce a new line within the button, but it only added a comma. Is there a way to add more than one line of text within a button, or is this just a limitation of the language?

**Failed new line within the button**

[image: Failed Multi-line Button]

**DCL Code snippet**

```lisp
// Revision
: boxed_column {
    key = "Column_Revision" ;
    label = "Revision Line" ;
    : row { // Row 08 - Quick Choices
        key = "Row_Buttons" ;
        : button {
            key = "btn_IFC" ;
            label = "Issued for\nConstruction" ;
        }// button
        : button {
            key = "tbn_AB" ;
            label = "As\nBuilt" ;
        }// button
        : radio_column {
            key = "RadioCol_WriteMethod" ;
            : radio_button {
                key = "rbtn_Owt" ;
                label = "Clear && Overwrite" ;
            }// radio_button
            : radio_button {
                key = "rbtn_Apnd" ;
                label = "Append / New Line" ;
            }// radio_button
        } //radio_column
    } //row
    : spacer ;

    : row { // Row 09 - Revision Details
        key = "Row_Labels" ;
        // Omitted Code
    }// row
}// boxed_column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, multiline text on buttons is not possible using standard DCL - you would need to turn to OpenDCL or similar.